# I'm having problems getting sql data in a table to pivot. I'm getting incorrect values

Tags: t-sql, pivot, partitioning

I have the following data that I need to pivot:

[image: image of results]

there is more data but this is a good representation. There are several samples. The results column is a derived field.

I have tried `pivot (max(results) for question in [OFFSET DIRECTION],[OFFSET DISTANCE],[REFERENCE LINE],[STATION NUMBER],[THICKNESS]`

I get pivoted data and the first set of rows (each with a new sample) with good data but starting with scmn (specimen number) is pulling data from other samples. I have tried various `row_number() over (partition by sample, scmn order by sample, scmn) as [control]` but nothing is working.

What I need is:
[[image: what I need2]

I have spent many days on this and am hitting a wall. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is sample code:

```
 drop table if exists smpl_rslt;
CREATE TABLE SMPL_RSLT
([SAMPLE] INT, QUESTION VARCHAR(100),VAL_NUM decimal(13,5), VAL_TXT VARCHAR(10),TST_STEP INT, SCMN INT)
INSERT INTO SMPL_RSLT VALUES
(732171,'Offset Direction',null, 'L',11,1),
(732171,'Offset Direction', null, 'L', 11, 2),
(732171,'Offset Direction',null,'L', 11,3),
(732171,'Offset Distance', 0.0000000, null, 13,1),
(732171,'Offset Distance', 0.0000000, null, 13,2),
(732171,'Offset Distance', 0.0000000, null, 13,3),
(732171,'Refence Line', null,'Centerline', 10,1),
(732171,'Refence Line', null,'Centerline', 10,2),
(732171,'Refence Line', null,'Centerline', 10,3),
(732171,'Station Number', null,'101+00', 5,1),
(732171,'Station Number', null,'101+05', 5,2),
(732171,'Station Number', null,'101+10', 5,3),
(732171,'Thickness', 6.500000,null, 14,1),
(732171,'Thickness', 6.500000,null, 14,2),
(732171,'Thickness', 6.500000,null, 14,3),
(732172,'Offset Direction',null, 'R',11,1),
(732172,'Offset Direction', null, 'R', 11, 2),
(732172,'Offset Direction',null,'R', 11,3),
(732172,'Offset Distance', 0.0000000, null, 13,1),
(732172,'Offset Distance', 0.0000000, null, 13,2),
(732172,'Offset Distance', 0.0000000, null, 13,3),
(732172,'Refence Line', null,'Right Edge', 10,1),
(732172,'Refence Line', null,'Right Edge', 10,2),
(732172,'Refence Line', null,'Right Edge', 10,3),
(732172,'Station Number', null,'210+00', 5,1),
(732172,'Station Number', null,'210+00', 5,2),
(732172,'Station Number', null,'210+00', 5,3),
(732172,'Thickness', 10.500000,null, 14,1),
(732172,'Thickness', 10.200000,null, 14,2),
(732172,'Thickness', 10.000000,null, 14,3);
select * from SMPL_RSLT    


    use test;
select [sample],[station number], [REFERENCE LINE],[OFFSET DIRECTION], [OFFSET DISTANCE],[THICKNESS] 
from (
    SELECT  [sample],question,IIF(COALESCE(CAST(VAL_NUM AS VARCHAR(10)), VAL_TXT) = '','TEST IN PROGRESS',COALESCE(CAST(VAL_NUM AS VARCHAR(10)), VAL_TXT))AS RESULT
    ,row_number() over (partition by [sample],question order BY [sample], question) spcmn
    from SMPL_RSLT) t
    pivot (max(result) for question in 
        ([station number], [REFERENCE LINE],[OFFSET DIRECTION], [OFFSET DISTANCE],[THICKNESS])) p
```

Reference line is not showing values

Comment: Can you add your table and sample dat scripts. The output and data is not really clear.  If you can add them I can have a look.  Thanks

Comment: I'll have to create them. I am working with my works sql database so the query I have won't help you.

Comment: this is more than enough. Ill prepare and add the solution.  Thanks

Comment: I just posted my answer, your Pivot statement had a issue. It is case sensitive as you deal with column values.  That is the issue which resulted Reference column NULL. I corrected that. Check the query and let me know any help needed.

Comment: Error was, [REFENCE LINE] had a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used wrong column values for the PIVOT which resulted you in NULL for Reference.  Make sure you copy and paste column names when you use them in PIVOTS. That was the issue here. Error was [REFENCE LINE] had a spelling mistake. Avoid this, copy and paste column values when using them in PIVOTS as PIVOTS dealing with rows values.

1st without block column names

```
       select [sample],[Station Number], [Refence Line],[Offset Direction], [Offset Distance] ,[Thickness]
      from (
         SELECT  
         [sample]
         ,question,IIF(COALESCE(CAST(VAL_NUM AS VARCHAR(10)), VAL_TXT) = '','TEST IN PROGRESS',COALESCE(CAST(VAL_NUM AS VARCHAR(10)), VAL_TXT))AS RESULT
        ,row_number() over (partition by [sample],question order BY  [sample], question) spcmn
         from SMPL_RSLT
         ) t
    pivot
       (
         max(result) 
             for question in  ([Station Number], [Refence Line],[Offset Direction], [Offset Distance] ,[Thickness])
        ) p
       ORDER BY P.[Refence Line]
```

[image: Result]

If you need to get capital column names in your query.

2nd with block column names

```
     select [sample],[Station Number], [Refence Line],[Offset Direction], [Offset Distance] ,[Thickness]
     from (
        SELECT  
       [sample]
       ,question AS [question]
       ,IIF(COALESCE(CAST(VAL_NUM AS VARCHAR(10)), VAL_TXT) = '','TEST IN PROGRESS',COALESCE(CAST(VAL_NUM AS VARCHAR(10)), VAL_TXT))AS RESULT
      ,row_number() over (partition by [sample],question order BY  [sample], question) spcmn
        from SMPL_RSLT
        ) t
     pivot
      (
        max(result) 
         for question in  ([STATION NUMBER], [REFENCE LINE],[OFFSET DIRECTION], [OFFSET DISTANCE] ,[THICKNESS])
      ) p
     ORDER BY P.[Refence Line]
```

[image: Result]